# is there an alternative to ISOVIEW

Tags: alternate

I have to access   an online  maintenance and it requires   ISOVIEW  to view diagrams and  graphics  but I am using  14.04 and hate the thought of having to do it through Windows

Comment: What format opens that program?

Answer (score 1):

Although I've never tried it myself, the included OpenOffice/LibreOffice DRAW program claims to view and manipulate vector illustrations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a linux build of ISOVIEW on this website - http://cactuscode.org/documentation/visualization/IsoView/

Install instructions are

- Get the IsoView source
- Untar the package and enter the IsoView directory
- Alter the make file, changing the second line to match your TCPXX
  installation
- If you did NOT install fltk to its normal place, or it is not in your
  path, you will need to edit the makefile some more
- At this point, if everything is setup correctly, and the code gods
  smile, then all you should need to do is 'make'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view and edit vector images, I think that Inkscape is your choice.

> Inkscape is a free and open-source vector graphics editor; it can
>   create or edit vector graphics such as illustrations, diagrams, line
>   arts, charts, logos and even complex paintings. Inkscape's primary
>   vector graphics format is Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) version 1.1.
>   It can import from or export to several other formats as well but all
>   editing workflow must inevitably occur within the constraints of SVG
>   format.

In a terminal - `sudo apt-get install inkscape`